# Does Lusin's theorem hold for $E = (-\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Lusin's Theorem states:

> Let $f$ be a measurable real-valued function on $[a,b]$, then given $\delta > 0$ there exists a continuous function $\phi$ on $[a,b]$ such that $m\{x: \phi(x) \neq f(x)\} < \delta$.

Is this true for the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$? I cannot think of a counterexample. I feel like it is not true, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Write the real line as a union of countably many disjoint closed unit intervals $\{I_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ and open gap intervals $\{J_n\}_{n \ge 1}$, where $|J_n|=\epsilon/4^n$.
In each $I_n$ find a continuous function $\phi_n$ that agrees with $f$ except on a set of measure $\epsilon/4^n$. Now define $\phi $ which agrees with $\phi_n$ on each $I_n$,and linearly interpolates on each gap interval $J_n$ using the known values at the endpoints.